# Dont understand why my method isnt being called

Tags: vb.net, oop

There are several file handlers my site uses, and they all had repeating code. In an effort to tidy up I created a common base class they can all inherit:

```
Public MustInherit Class HandlerBase
Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Public Overridable Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        RequestHandler(context)
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub RequestHandler(ByVal context As HttpContext)
    Select Case context.Request.HttpMethod
        Case "GET"
            GetFile(context)
        Case "POST"
            UploadFile(context)
        Case "DELETE"
            DeleteFile(context)
        Case Else
            context.Response.ClearHeaders()
            context.Response.StatusCode = 405
    End Select
End Sub

Protected MustOverride Sub GetFile(ByVal context As HttpContext)
Protected MustOverride Sub UploadFile(ByVal context As HttpContext)
Protected MustOverride Sub DeleteFile(ByVal context As HttpContext)

end class
```

Two of my handlers work perfectly after inheriting the base class, but one doesn't seem to fire at all. The only difference is that this handler overrides RequestHandler:

```
Protected Overrides Sub RequestHandler(ByVal context As HttpContext)
    Select Case context.Request.HttpMethod
        Case "GET"
            GetFile(context)
        Case Else
            context.Response.ClearHeaders()
            context.Response.StatusCode = 405
    End Select
End Sub
```

I access the handler and ProcessRequest is never called in base nor RequestHandler

Answer (score 0):

Found this was a small typo after inspecting the request in fiddler:

```
Protected Overrides Sub DeleteFile(ByVal context As HttpContext
    Throw New NotImplementedException()
End Sub
```

Missing a closing brackets for paramaters. Ill vote to close this.